# Complex numbers and circles

Tags: complex-numbers

**Question:**

> Let the complex numbers $\alpha$ and $1\over \bar\alpha$ lie on
>   circles $$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2$$ and $$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 =
>  4r^2$$ respectively. If $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$ satisfies the equation
>   $$2|z_0| = r^2 + 2$$ then find the value of $|\alpha|$.

I tried for a while, but couldn't get anywhere. A small hint would be appreciated

Comment: Where is $\alpha$ involved?

Comment: @Matthias Ummm... first line? It lies on the circles defined.

Comment: Ah ok $x$ and $y$ are your 2d coordinates. $=>$ is $\geq$ or better $=$?

Comment: @Matthias It's supposed to be equal. I guess the background block messed with it.

Comment: So, the equations to solve for $|\alpha|$ are $|\alpha - z_0| = r$, $| \alpha/|\alpha|^2  - z_0| = 2r$ and $2 |z_0| = r^2 + 2$.

Comment: If my interpretation of the question is correct, one solution is $r = 0$, $z_0 = 1$ and $\alpha = 1$, but $r= 0$ does not create circles.

Comment: @Dominic108: I think that the idea is that $r$ is fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed?  I already assumed that we want r > 0, because r=0 does not define circles,  but I don't know what fixed would mean here.

Comment: Let $u = \bar \alpha /|\alpha|$.  One hint is that we can replace $z_0$ with  $z_0' = u z_0$ and $\alpha$ with $\alpha' = u \alpha$ and the equations remain the same, but now $\alpha'$ has no imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $1/\alpha=\bar{\alpha}/|\alpha|^2$. Now, you can procede setting $\alpha=x+iy$ and solving system of linear equations.

Comment: I don't see how you get linear equations. My hint is way more useful, because you get rid of the imaginary part. You can now solve for $\alpha = x + 0i$.